# What is the idiomatic way of populating a KnockoutJS backed form with asynchronously fetched data?

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js, idioms

What would be the idiomatic way to populate a KnockoutJS-backed form with data that is fetched asynchronously from a server using HTTP GET? The issue I'm running into is that if I don't create an empty dummy instance of the domain model (see code below), Knockout breaks because it tries to call `domainModel().name` and `domainModel().description` for the form fields before the `$.getJSON` call is finished.

What is the common way of handling this situation? Should I do the `$.getJSON` first and call `ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(domainModelData));` in the success callback or is there some other way?

**HTML & inline Javascript:**

```
<form data-bind="submit: update">
    <input id="name" data-bind="value: domainModel().name"/>
    <input id="description" data-bind="value: domainModel().description"/>
    <button type="submit"/>     
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
    });
</script>
```

**The Knockout view model:**

```
function DomainModel(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.id = ko.observable(data.id);
    self.name = ko.observable(data.name);
    self.description = ko.observable(data.description);
}

function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    // This feels somehow dirty
    self.domainModel = ko.observable(new DomainModel({id: null, name: "", description: ""}));

    self.update = function() {
        ...
    };

    $.getJSON("domainModel/<id>", function(domainModelData) {
        self.domainModel(new DomainModel(domainModelData));
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the with binding or foreach binding to ensure the object exists before the bindings attempt to resolve -

```
<form data-bind="submit: update, with: domainModel">
    <input id="name" data-bind="value: name"/>
    <input id="description" data-bind="value: description"/>
    <button type="submit"/>     
</form>
```

Basically, until domainModel has a value name and description will not be resolved.  Another approach is to use a $data. prefix to say 'if there is no data, wait until there is'

```
<form data-bind="submit: update">
    <input id="name" data-bind="value: $data.domainModel().name"/>
    <input id="name" data-bind="value: $data.domainModel().description"/>
    <button type="submit"/>     
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you, this answers my question. What if I wanted to show the empty form until it is populated or even allow for the case that it is not populated but should be filled from scratch by the user? Currently the form will not show up at all if domainModel never gets populated. I guess this would require the empty DomainModel instance?

Comment: You mean to show empty elements (inputs) inside of the form and apply bindings after domainModel is loaded up?  That's easy, let me update my answer to include the VM.  --- Edit --- After looking at your code the only thing you would need to change is assigning a dummy value to the ID for it to work, or using the $data.domainModel().Id approach for any value that is undefined or null.

Comment: Ok I retract my previous comment, you don't need to set an ID because you aren't binding to it in the view, so you can leave it null and let the server assign an ID or go out and perform logic to assign one yourself.  As-is your view model would create an empty DomainModel object until getJSON is called and so it should be working properly.